# exchange first and last characters in a word or a string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code snippet that does a job of replacing first and last character from a given string, which works correctly:

```
def front_back(s1):
if len(s1) == 1:
    return s1
else:
    convert_to_list = list(s1)
    temp_list = convert_to_list[0], convert_to_list[-1]
    convert_to_list[-1] = temp_list[0]
    convert_to_list[0] = temp_list[1]
    s1 = ''.join(convert_to_list)
    return s1

inpt1 = input('Enter string :')
print(front_back(inpt1))
```

Output I get is :

```
front_back('code') -- 'eodc'
```

In the above code what modifications I can make, to make it more effective, since I know you can achieve it using slicing function.
Also, how can i make this code work for a string with two words:

```
input: 'hello world'

output should be: 'oellh dorlw'
```

since currently it just replaces the first character `i.e. 'ello worlh'`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:

```
def front_back(s1):
    if len(s1) == 1:
        return s1
    else:
        newlist = []
        convert_to_list = s1.split()
        for each in convert_to_list:
            each_list = list(each)
            firstC, lastC = each_list[0], each_list[-1]

            each_list[0] = lastC
            each_list[-1] = firstC

            newword = ''.join(each_list)
            newlist.append(newword)


    return ' '.join(newlist)

inpt1 = input('Enter string :')
print(front_back(inpt1))
```

Comment: using the reverse function will reverse the full string, however i just want to interchange first and last characters of the words. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, now I understand your question, please check the edited, you just need to account for each word.